# How to extract beer names with XPATH in Python from this hungarian webshop?

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping

I am trying to extract product information of beers from a hungarian webshop Spar. My code only seems to work and extract the product names when I don't filter to beers. So in case page_url = ('https://www.spar.hu/onlineshop/') then the code works fine but when trying to use the link below in my code, it extracts nothing. I have also tried using the link for total alcohol category but same as when using the beers one.

### The code itself:

```
import requests
from scrapy import Selector


headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36'
}

page_url = ('https://www.spar.hu/onlineshop/alkoholos-italok/sor-cider/c/H8-6/?page=1')

html = requests.get(url = page_url, headers = headers).content

sel = Selector(text = html)

for card in sel.xpath('//div[@class= "productBox"]'):
    name = card.xpath('//label[@class="productTitle"]/a/text()').extract()
    print(name)
```

Comment: You can use browser's developer tools to see if your xpath is valid or not. When I open the url mentioned in your code and check `//div[@class= "productBox"]` it is an overlayed box that doesn't have any of the information you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are sending a GET request, the URL you mentioned above will only return it's source code.

The source code doesn't include the products, but only a Javascript which will then load the products from a different URL.

If you open up your URL in a Webbrowser and press CTRL+U you will see the source code.
If you drill into the page by opening the developer tools in your Webbrowser (F12) and reload the page, you can actually see all the content that the page loads.

When using the network inspection in the developer tools you will come accross this URL: https://sp1004e537.guided.lon5.atomz.com/?page=1&category=H8-6&callback=parseResponse&sp_cs=UTF-8&sort=product-ecr-sortlev&m_sortProdResults_egisp=a&pos=6108207&callback=parseResponse&_=1606416848605

This is the actual URL which returns the list of products as a Json file.

Here is the complete Code for this page:

```
import requests
import json

headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36'
}

page_url = ('https://sp1004e537.guided.lon5.atomz.com/?page=1&category=H8-6&sp_cs=UTF-8&sort=product-ecr-sortlev&m_sortProdResults_egisp=a&pos=6108207&_=1606416848605')

r = requests.get(url = page_url, headers = headers)

if r.status_code == 200:
    j = json.loads(r.text[14:-1]) # remove non Json string from the beginning and end parseResponse( [....] ) 
    for beer in j['results']:
        print(beer['title-hu'])
```

I highly recommend to debug the dictionary "beer" since it includes a lot more information.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I have managed to find the link you have mentioned. Is there any way to get this link from the source code or the only way is to add it to the Python code and hope it won't change daily?

I am strugglig with the same extraction at 2 other webshops:
https://kifli.hu/c300113077-vilagos-sor
https://www.groby.hu/alkoholos-italok/sor

These seems a bit harder as I have to scroll and click on show more in case I want to get  all the products but it seems they are also loaded from another url.

Comment: @MátéPelsőczi i don't recommend to try and read the API url out of the source code. Simply because devs usually don't like to update their API url and if they do, its part of a bigger change which would modify the source code as well. Also, the API url is usually generated by Javascript,...

For your second page, you would want to remove the `[14:-1]` after `r.text` since it responses with pure Json. Regarding the load more, you would need to increment the offset or tweak with the limit. https://kifli.hu/services/frontend-service/products/300113077?offset=40&limit=10

Answer (score 0):

You could just add a `.` just before you second xpath, use `get()` instead of `extract()` and do a little bit of trimming on the result string.

With the following code :

```py
for card in sel.xpath('//div[@class= "productBox"]'):
    name = card.xpath('.//label[@class="productTitle"]/a/text()').get()
    print(name)
```

i get this result:
**Tchibo Cafissimo Special őrölt, pörkölt kávékapszula 6 x 10 db 471 g**